# How can i link the "UserID" with the "username" so i can update my table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

Here is my query:

```
$query = ("UPDATE users SET username='$username', password='$password', email='$email' WHERE userID = '79'");

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Instead of updating user 79, I want to update the person who is logged in. Therefore, instead of putting `79`, would I put `$_SESSION`?. If so, the session is linked to the username, not the user ID. So I was wondering, how can I link the username which the person is logged in on, with the userID that associates with it?

Sorry, I am new to this forum.

When they log in, they only type in their username and password. They do not type in their userID. So how can i grab the userID when it isnt being posted through a form? I somehow need to link the username (that they type in), with their userID.

Comment: Put the userid in their session when the login. Then you have it whenever you need it.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Having username in session only with no user id, wont help much in larger application. Instead of saving user_id into session directly, this of storing the user id and associated fields into an identity object, then store the identity object in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Stored the user ID as well when you store the user name in $_SESSION. You just need to write `$_SESSION['UserID']='USER_ID_VALUE'`

Doing that you'll be able to access the user id while the user has an active session.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the perils of rolling your own session management system. If you've never done it before you will make a lot of mistakes. Some of these mistakes will be very serious. This is why using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to give you a good foundation is almost always a good idea.

In general, when you successfully login you should capture the ID of the user that was logged in. The username can't be presumed to be consistent over time, but the ID will be.

Then you can perform updates vs. this ID.

Keep in mind that with an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) this would be extremely easy. The way you're going about it here makes it intentionally difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
$identity = new stdClass();
$identity->user_id =123;
$identity->username = 'john';

$_SESSION['identity'] = $identity;

// usage without checks,

$identity = $_SESSION['identity'];
echo $identity->user_id;
```